# How should I send my bitcoins to my wallet from coinbase

Tags: coinbase.com, bitgo

I just bought Bitcoins with Coinbase site, and as I read about bitcoin, everybody say I shouldn't let my bitcoins in Coinbase, as I don't have the private keys.

So I opened a bitGo Wallet, and try to send some bitcoins there, but If I want to send 10 euros, it cost me 31.22 euros to send it...

I don't understand it. Can anyone help me understand why ?

Comment: Well you don't have full control of you funds on BitGo. ["BitGo Instant wallets consist of 3 keys: one held by BitGo, one held by the user, and one held on behalf of the user by a third-party Key Recovery Service (KRS)."](https://www.bitgo.com/solutions#wallet)

Comment: Anyway, your question is to avoid the high transaction fee. The best solution is to transfer your BTC from Coinbase to GDAX(Coinbase's dedicated exchange), then send from GDAX to your own wallet. The whole process is free from fees.

Comment: I vote to close because of "primarily opinion based answers".

Comment: I would tell "experienced based" :)

Comment: By the way, if BitGo is not the one, do you know any recommandable web wallet ?

Comment: I only know of one Bitcoin web wallet provider/exchange that allow their customers full control of their private key(s). Blockchain.info is the one. If you ask my recommendation, I would say go for a SPV wallet like Electrum. Also you can use GDAX to send to your chosen btc wallet, if you want to avoid fees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 10 euros in Bitcoin, it is currently not worth sending to your wallet. The current Bitcoin transaction fees average around $50 USD today. You can see [the chart here](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html). This is because there is an enormous amount of Bitcoin transaction, but only a few transactions can fit in the 1mb block.

If you had much more money, you should definitely send them in a wallet you own the private keys. Some exchanges like [Mt. Gox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mt._Gox) closed and millions worth of Bitcoins were lost. There's a lot of fire right now in the Bitcoin community, so owning your coins is a good start.

Comment: Well, 10 euros is for testing, I bought 200 euros

Comment: The current state of Bitcoin could not be described otherwise as unusable for small transactions due to the massive influx of new buyers. If you want to transfer your coins while minimizing fees you should look at Bitcoin Cash (Cheapest transaction fees on Coinbase) or Ethereum (Fastest on Coinbase). But transferring Bitcoins will cost you atleast $50 USD today if you want it transferred fast.

Comment: Right now, I can t buy bitcoin cash with Coinbase. But so, if I can't transfer them, I can't own them... I dont understand the logic...

Comment: Coinbase owns the private keys associated with your Bitcoins, if someone seizes them, they are lost. As said earlier, you can still transfer you Bitcoins but you will pay high mining fees due to a clogged network